# Docker is limiting the network speed when the host OS is idle

Tags: networking, download, docker, home-networking, bittorrent

Something weird is happening with my containerized torrent download speed.

I tested with deluge and qbittorrent within a docker container.

When I **start a download it starts fast, then it slows down** after ~1 minutes (around 500 Kb/s).

What is really weird is, that **if I start any download on the host OS, the torrent download goes fast**.

If I try to download the SAME torrent with qBittorrent from the host OS (outside of docker), the download speed is good AND increases the download speed within the docker container.
**If I stop downloading on the host OS, the download speed decreases back to around 500 Kb/s in the dockerized torrent client**.

Weirder **if I open a terminal to the container**, and I go into the download folder **and start a huge file download with `wget` it's lightning-fast**, and the torrent download inside the docker speeds up as well.

So this is not a networking or a disk IO problem, since I can download a file and write the disk fast even directly from the container outside of the torrent client.

I am after 24hrs of debugging session, I've tried everything I could find on the internet:

- tested different containers (deluge and qbittorrent)
- deluge `ltConfig` plugin with Best Performance Seed settings
- Several VPN servers and providers (NordVPN, Mullvad)
- Several proxy settings (with and without VPN)
- Everything is the same without VPN and/or proxy
- disk IO speed is perfect
- completely destroyed the container and deleted the images and networks and rebuilt
- factory reset and tried that way (deleted config folder and rebuilt the container)
- 100% OS reinstall from scratch

Nothing helped, the only way to get the expected download speed in the container if I start a download that is not within the dockerized torrent client.

It feels like the dockerized torrent client needs a heavy load from outside to be able to use the full bandwidth, and when the network is idling it limits the network speed for some reason.

I am using `Ubuntu 20.4`